# Phonegap run android error on windows 8.1: not recognizing User name in command

Tags: android, windows, cordova, windows-8.1

I am trying to use Phonegap on Windows 8.1 system for Android development. I have connected my admin account with my Outlook account. So my User name is "Aditya Mohan".

When I try running the command

> phonegap run android

it gives the error

```
'C:\Users\Aditya' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
[error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

It is giving error with only half part of the User name.
I can't change my account name.
Please provide a solution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****FIX****

If your like me this has had you running in circles trying to throw your Dev Machine out the window.

Its actually quit simple.

A lot of older systems developed are unable to recognize special character sets and that includes the space, well sense you cant change your account name on your Windows Device, What should you do?

I don't recommend using your "Users" folder but that is an option, simply don't put your project in a folder address that uses [SPACES] or special characters. Keep it clean and concise, works better in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Make a Phonegap folder on the root of C and do your phonegap create command in that directory